# What is the energy ordering of molecular orbitals in diatomic molecules of third and fourth period elements?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

For diatomic molecules with less than 16 electrons, the list of molecular orbitals in order of increasing energy is:

σ<sub>1s</sub> < σ*<sub>1s</sub> < σ<sub>2s</sub> < σ*<sub>2s</sub> < (π<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> = π<sub>2p<sub>z</sub></sub>) < σ<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> < (π*<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> = π*<sub>2p<sub>z</sub></sub>) < σ*<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub>

From O<sub>2</sub> onwards, because of s-p mixing, the order of energies of the molecular orbitals changes to:

σ<sub>1s</sub> < σ*<sub>1s</sub> < σ<sub>2s</sub> < σ*<sub>2s</sub> < σ<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub> < (π<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> = π<sub>2p<sub>z</sub></sub>) < (π*<sub>2p<sub>y</sub></sub> = π*<sub>2p<sub>z</sub></sub>) < σ*<sub>2p<sub>x</sub></sub>

I now want to know how the molecular orbital theory can be extended to diatomic molecules of heavier elements, such as Cl<sub>2</sub> and Br<sub>2</sub>.

More precisely, what is the order of energies of molecular orbitals formed by the combination of atomic orbitals from the 3s, 3p, 4s, 3d and 4p subshells?

Comment: Heavier elements do not tend to form diatomic molecules, with $\ce{Cl2}$ and $\ce{Br2}$ being an exception.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Diatomic molecules are pretty tough to make for most elements, but in gas phase they fare perfectly well. For ex. making W2 vapor can be challenging, but the bond in there is rather impressive.